# How to line up flex box columns beside eachother

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to line up 3 different columns under the same class using flexbox.
But when i enter the HTML on my browser, all the content in the different containers are lined in a single line from top too bottom, instead of having the columns beside each other from left to right, and the items inside goes from top to bottom.

Here is the relevant part of the HTML code(all inside the body tag.)

```html
<div class="container">
      <article class="text item">
        <a href="https://www.foxnews.com/category/person/joe-biden">President
          Biden</a> is set to meet with Ukrainian <a href="#">President Volodymyr Zelensky</a>
         at the White House on Wednesday – a visit that is expected to build on
         and amplify the bilateral relationship, and to underscore the United
         States’ "ironclad" commitment to Ukraine’s security and sovereignty,
         senior administration officials said.
      </article>

      <p class="text item">
        The two leaders have spoken twice by phone – once in April, and once in
        June before <a href="https://www.shorturl.at/puMQX">Biden met with
        Russian President Vladimir Putin in Geneva</a>.
      </p>

      <p class="text item">
        Senior administration officials said Biden and Zelensky will chair an
        expanded bilateral meeting with their key advisers, and will later
        transition to a one-on-one conversation, giving them "the space to
        communicate with one another more directly."
      </p>
    </div>

    <a href="#" class="text seperator">FLASHBACK: BIDEN ASSURES ZELENSKY HE WILL STAND UP FOR
      UKRAINE SOVEREIGNTY IN PUTIN SUMMIT
    </a>


    <div class="container">
      <p class="text items">
        Officials said Biden will convey his <em>"ironclad commitment"</em> to
        Ukraine’s security, sovereignty and Euro-Atlantic aspirations. Biden
        is also expected to discuss the security situation that Ukraine is
        facing, as the nation continues to see <a href="#">acts of Russian
        aggression</a> in the region.
      </p>

      <p class="text items">
        Biden also will discuss ways in which the U.S. could continue to provide
        security assistance to Ukraine, officials said – noting that the U.S
        . will provide a new $60 million security assistance package for Ukraine
        that will include additional Javelin anti-armor systems and other
        defensive lethal and non-lethal capabilities.
      </p>

      <p class="text items">
        So far, the U.S. has committed $2.5 billion in support of Ukraine forces
         since 2014, including more than $400 million in 2021 alone.
      </p>

      <p class="text items">
        As for reform, Biden is set to discuss the ways in which Ukraine has made
         "progress on governance, rule of law, and anti-corruption reforms since
         2014." Biden, while serving as vice president for former President
         Obama, was tasked with overseeing the administration’s Ukraine policy.
      </p>

      <p class="text items">
        The president is also expected to discuss cooperation efforts to bolster
         collaboration on shared energy and climate goals, including through a
         reinvigorated Strategy Energy and Climate Dialogue, which officials say
         would give a "strong" platform to "advance energy security objectives,
         enhance economic ties, and achieve ambitious climate targets."
      </p>
    </div>

    <a href="#" class="text seperator">BIDEN SAYS UKRAINE HAS NOT MET NATO MEMBERSHIP CRITERIA</a>

    <div class="container">
      <p class="text items">
        As for the <a href="https://www.shorturl.at/lxCF2">coronavirus pandemic
        </a>, officials said the U.S. has "stood shoulder-to-shoulder" with the
        Zelensky administration, and has already provided $55 million in
        COVID-related assistance, and donated nearly 2.2 million doses of COVID
        vaccines to Ukraine.
      </p>

      <p class="text items">
        "We intend to continue providing assistance to Ukraine, including cold
         chain storage support and an additional $12.8 million in COVID
         -related assistance," an official said.
      </p>

      <p class="text items">
        Officials said the U.S. will also provide an additional $45 million in
        humanitarian assistance to help address Ukrainians who remain impacted
        by the <a href="https://www.shorturl.at/eyFJX">crisis with Russia.</a>
      </p>

      <p class="text items">
        Meanwhile, senior administration officials said that after the meeting,
         the U.S. and Ukraine will announce the reinvigoration of the Strategic
          Partnership Commission, which they say has not met in three years.
      </p>

      <p class="text items">
        Senior administration officials said they anticipate a meeting this fall
        between Secretary of State Antony Blinken and Ukraine’s foreign minister
        to approve a new charter between the U.S. and Ukraine that will "set
        out the parameters for how we can work closely together to meet these
        <a href="https://www.shorturl.at/efBPU">21st-century challenges</a>."
      </p>
    </div>
```

and here is the relevant CSS included.

CSS:

```css
.container
{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: center;
}


.items
{
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 3;
  align-self: auto;
}
```

Comment: If you want columns then this is wrong `flex-flow: column wrap;` it should be `flex-flow: row wrap;`

Comment: that puts all the columns from top to bottom, and the items inside from left to right. I am trying to get the items from top to bottom, and the columns from left to right. i don't know if I can do that, or if I have to approach it differently @Paulie_D. But thanks for the tip :)

Comment: So you want the containers to be next to each other? Use flexbox on the parent (body?) with `flex-flow:row wrap`

Comment: ahh, that makes more sense! Thank you for the tio @Paulie_D :)